# how to add customize map pointer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pointers, maps

I would like to insert custom pointer in my maps. but i don't know how to insert my custom pointer in my map

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

 function init() {

     var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 12,
              panControl: false,
              zoomControl: true,
              zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
              }, 
              draggable: false,
              mapTypeControl: false,
              streetViewControl: false,
              scaleControl: true,
              scrollwheel: false,
              navigationControl: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.000841, 80.342339), // New York
              styles: [
                {"featureType":"water",
                 "elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#d1cdc0"}]},
                {"featureType":"landscape",
                 "elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#f1ede0"}]},
                {"featureType":"poi", "elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#d8d4c7"}]},
                {"featureType":"road.highway", "elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#c6c2b5"}]},
                {"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#cecabd"},{"lightness":-20}]},
                {"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#d1cdc0"},{"lightness":-17}]},
                {"elementType":"labels.text.stroke",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"visibility":"on"},{"weight":0.9}]},
                {"elementType":"labels.text.fill",
                 "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1c180b"}]},
                {"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels",
                 "stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},
                {"elementType":"labels.icon",
                 "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},
                {"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#c2beb1"},{"lightness":-10}]},
                {},
                {"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry",
                 "stylers":[{"color":"#c2beb1"},{"weight":0.7}]}
              ]
      };
      var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}
var markerImage = 'map_pointer.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: markerImage
});
```

Comment: See the [documentation on custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can set relative address to custom image at line :

```
var markerImage = 'map_pointer.png';
```

for example you can set :

```
var markerImage = 'pointers/custom-image.png';
```

another example of define icons for pointers

```
// Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Custom Title",
                    icon: 'pointers/custom-image.png'

                });
```

you defiend marker outside of map initialization function. I have edited your code please look at this demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/rskh26c4/)

Comment: http://trilanka.com/test/map.html

Check this URL..the map pointer is not showing up

Comment: your error is ReferenceError: latLng is not defined instead of line `position: latLng`  your lat and lang pos variable name is myLatlng so you must use : `position: myLatlng ` also in title variable you can use custom text for title of pointer. and finaly you can define relative address to your custom icon

Comment: still it's not coming..pls chk the same URL

Comment: because you defiend marker outside of map initialization function. I have edited your code please look at this demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/rskh26c4/)

Comment: added dude..i have posted another doubt ...pls chk if u can solve..or drop ur email id ...v ill b touch ??